# Ruby client for Tzkt WebSocket API

Tags: ruby, signalr

It's possible to connect a ruby client to a webSocket Api based on SignalR. I didn't find any library or gem for that.

https://api.tzkt.io/#section/Python-simple-client

Comment: Unfortunately there's no up-to-date Ruby library for SignalR indeed, the only option is to implement it yourself (actually only a subset of it including WS transport).
Here is our golang implementation for the reference: https://github.com/dipdup-net/go-lib/tree/master/tzkt/events/signalr